# Xamarin Resource ID #0x7f050000 type #0x12 is not valid

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I read few similar threads here, but none of the solutions works. I am pretty new in Xamarin Programming.
This is the code that creates the problem:

```
try
{
    var combo = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Guardian.Resource.Id.spinner, gdm.Porgram_names);
    combo.Adapter = adapter;
}
catch (Exception exc)
{

}
```

My app crashes and this message appears (try catch block dosen't catch it):

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050000 type #0x12 is not valid

When i comment this line: `combo.Adapter=adapter;` the program doesn't crash.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What is `Guardian.Resource.Id.spinner`? Is that a layout or just a single item?

Comment: yeah I had the same issue.. thanks for posting this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter to ArrayAdapter needs to be a `Resource.Layout` resource that determines how each row in the List is displayed.

It cannot be a `Resource.Id` value.

In other words, you've found the Spinner by an ID, then you need to say how you'd like to show the items within that Spinner using a layout.

For example,

```
new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, gdm.Porgram_names);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  omg that was driving me insane.. so much more complicated than creating comboboxes in WPF/Winforms lol.. helped me a lot =]